# How to Convert String value into date format

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my string value `20180421`

I want to convert this value into `2018/04/21`

here my code

```
$querya="SELECT STR_TO_DATE('$date','%m/%d/%Y');";
```

but i does not change my string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format is already in ISO format, so you can just use `date()` for the conversion:

```
select date(?)
```

You can *also* use `str_to_date()` but you need to use the correct format:

```
$querya = "SELECT STR_TO_DATE(?, '%Y%m%d')";
```

Note the use of `?`.  This is a parameter placeholder and indicates that you should pass the value in as a *parameter* rather than as a variable.

I should point out that `2018/04/21` is a particular format.  Dates are stored in an internal format.  To get a particular output format, you need to convert them to strings.  Here is one solution:

```
select date_format(date(?), '%Y/%m/%d')
```

The  `date()` function is optional, because MySQL will correctly convert this string to a date, so you can also use:

```
select date_format(?, '%Y/%m/%d')
```